# Maximize custom WPF form to be as the screen size

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm trying to create a custom form in WPF. I set the **windowStyle** to be **None**

I added 3 buttons :

1. Close
2. Max/Min
3. Hide

What I'm trying to do is when the user clicks on the second button is ,
if the form in normal state , maximize the form to be as the screen size, else if 
the form is on maximize state , set the form to the initial size..

This is what I tried, but nothing happens when I first click on the second button

```
  private bool maximized = false;
  private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!maximized)
        {
            this.MaxHeight = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;
            this.MaxWidth = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;
            this.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Maximized;
            maximized = true;
        }
        else
        {
            this.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Normal;
            maximized = false;
        }
    }
```

Am I need to add Invalidate or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I Solved it.. 
When I created the xaml file.. I added a rectangle so the form body will be the rectangle.. 
I needed to change the rectangle width and height instead..

```
  private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!maximized)
        {

            this.FormBody.Width = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Width; //rectangle's width
            this.FormBody.Height = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Height;// rectangle's height
            this.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Maximized;
            maximized = true;
        }
        else
        {
            this.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Normal;
            maximized = false;
        }
    }
```

I also change the `SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth` to be `SystemParameters.WorkArea.Width`
and also with the `Height` so in this way the form wont exceed the taskbar